# ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small

Tags: oracle, intervals

When I try to query differences between 2 timestamps in Oracle, the result returns the interval normally.

```
select NVL2(ERROR_OUT_TS, ERROR_OUT_TS-ERROR_IN_TS, null) from table
```

or

```
select interval '8 00:00:10' day to second from dual
```

But when I try to select rows with greater than some interval, Oracle give me this error.

```
where ERROR_OUT_TS - ERROR_IN_TS <=  '00 00:02:00'
```

or

```
where ERROR_OUT_TS - ERROR_IN_TS >= interval '0 00:00:10' day to second
```

It keeps saying that "the leading precision is too small".

I am trying to return the interval like 0 00:00:00:000
It is working fine for other customers. Only few customers are experiencing it.

How to choose the correct precision?

Comment: Can you post something reproducible for us?

Comment: I'm here for the same error. This is my statement:
SYSTIMESTAMP - NUMTODSINTERVAL (PI_TIME, 'MINUTE');
 So I guess, PI_TIME variable is too big or sth like that... Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select interval '8 00:00:10' day(4) to second(4) from dual;
```

What it does is that 'day' and 'second' are default 2 digits, this expands them to accept 4. You probably just need 3 though.